# JDBC version in Hibernate 4

Tags: database, hibernate, jdbc, db2, websphere

Is there a way, how to use Hibernate 4 (Hibernate ORM 4.2.21.Final) together with JDBC 3.0 driver? I made version upgrade from Hibernate 3 to 4, but then I realised, that there are some problems with unsupported methods (Feature is not implemented: PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream), because Hibernate 4 works with JDBC 4.0. Do I really have to move back to Hibernate 3 or can I just set some property into config to use JDBC 3.0? I am limited by the JDBC 3.0 driver running on Websphere 7 (JRE 6).

Comment: Why are you limited to using the JDBC 3 driver? JDBC 4 was introduced with Java 6, so if you are running on Java 6, then you can use a JDBC 4 driver.

Comment: But our customer uses on his Websphere only JDBC 3.0 driver

Comment: Upgrade the driver; I can't think of a reason why the JDBC 4 driver can't be used if you are running on Java 6. You should expect new technology to require modern specifications. JDBC 3.0 was introduced with Java 1.4 in 2002, JDBC 4.0 was introduced with Java 6 in 2006. The only other solution would be not to use Hibernate 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any other way apart from upgrading to JDBC 4.0. I myself have had similar problem when I upgraded from Hibernate from v3.0 to v4.2.

I don't know from where you get your information but as far as WebSphere 7.0 is concern, it does support JDBC 4.0 Specifications. You can read about it from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012369).

Comment: I know it supports, but the problem is, that I'm afraid it's not easy to convince our customer to upgrade the version. It would be long procedure, because there are more application running its Websphere and they would have to communicate this JDBC vesrion chage with many others suppliers.

Comment: Well! In that case you'll need to open another thread asking "How to convince the client for technological upgrades?".